# How to force Shotwell write metadata tags to video file?

Tags: video, shotwell, exif, exiftool

I have a set of photos and videos that shares a common tag in Shotwell. I'm able to verify those photo files in Nautilus and assert that this tag is written in it. This is confirmed either by exiftools. However, this does not happens in video files. Nautilus doesn't detect any tag, as well as exiftool.

This way, I'm supposing that Shotwell isn't writting this tag to video files. How can I fix this?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/18097/can-i-export-shotwell-pictures-database-saving-all-the-tags

Comment: What version are you running? Have yo tried v..23.4 which according to https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Shotwell became available July 20th and appears to have added further support for video and raw photo formats

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently [Shotwell Photo Manager](http://yorba.org/shotwell/help/) doesn't support editing video metadata, as described in the [Shotwell Help Files](http://yorba.org/shotwell/help/other-files.html), the [Shotwell mailing list](http://shotwell.yorba.narkive.com/jCNehTLZ/help-us-gather-information-about-video-file-metadata/), and the [Shotwell Architecture Overview](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Shotwell/Architecture/MetadataWriting/).

---

If you need a simple alternative option for single video metadata editing, I would suggest trying VLC.

Here's how to edit a videos' metadata using VLC.

- Click <kbd>[VLC](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/vlc) [image: Install VLC]</kbd> to auto-open Software Center and select <kbd>Install</kbd>,
  or visit the [Official page](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) to download the source code or select another system/architecture.
- Run VLC and open the video file you wish to change its metadata,
- Go to *Tools* > *Media Information*, 
  [image: VLC Media Information and video metadata]
- or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>, to open the *Current Media
  Information* window and edit the media information. 
  [image: VLC Current Media Information window]
- Click <kbd>Close</kbd> to save any changes you have made and you are good to go.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, Shotwell does not support writing meta-data to video files.

Also, the official Bug tracker for requests is [here](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Shotwell)

Answer (score 1):

Try setting preferences in `shotwell` to write directly to the file as shown below. If that doesn't work you might try to write a plugin to extend `shotwell` functionality.

[image]

You can report bugs and ask questions of the developers [here.](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shotwell)

More information regarding Shotwell plugins:

https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Shotwell/Architecture/WritingPlugins
http://unit201.net/2015/02/27/shotwell-plugins-part-i-setup/

Comment: This option deals exclusively with photos. Not videos =/

Comment: @PedroAlves    According to the shotwell documentation they use the terms synonymously. See: http://yorba.org/shotwell/help/formats.html